# Responsive Menu Width in Safari

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on my first responsive website and having some issues with Safari. This is essentially the menu bar that I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/vHdJj/1/

Everything looks fine in Firefox and Chrome but in Safari a small sliver of the blue background appears on the right side of the menu...as if it's struggling to fill the width of the `ul` with the `li` elements.

When I continue to resize the browser window the small bar seems to shrink and then reappear randomly. Floating the `li` to the right fixes this but if possible I'd like to avoid having to reverse the menu items. How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: for starters do you have the meta tag included?

Comment: @PatsyIssa Yep, I've included the following meta tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: you should just set the background-color to the logo id. additionally make sure you set #navigation{overflow: hidden;} will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your background-color to the logo as @Parker Hutchinson said. Overflow hidden isn't needed in this case. - http://jsfiddle.net/rXXpr/

```
#logo {
  background-color: #003b6f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's an issue with margin/padding/width.  I've noticed there's differences between browsers when rendering, namely whether padding should be included in the specified width or added to it.  You might try this on the element with the blue bg:

-khtml-padding-right: 0px;

If that doesn't help try using the element inspector to zero in on it more.